# UITableView in an UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a problem over here. So what I'm trying to do is to add several TableViews inside a paged UIScrollView. I have a class called CustomView which is UITableView class. It works fine separately as a Table View. So there are no problems with it. So I tried to add them like this in .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface PagedScrollViewController : UIViewController {

    UIScrollView *scrollView;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end
```

and in .m:

```
    @synthesize scrollView;

        - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];
            int numberOfPages = 3;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
                CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i,
                                      0.0,
                                      self.scrollView.frame.size.width,
                                      self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
            CustomView *customView = [[CustomView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
            customView.view.frame = frame;
            [self.scrollView addSubview:customView.view];
        }

        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * numberOfPages,
                                                 self.scrollView.frame.size.height - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height);

    }
```

It shows just an empty table view without any cells. What am I doing wrong? By the way, it worked perfectly, before I started using storyboard. 
Thank you, in advance.

What is more, on iOS 5 I get an Sigabrt in console:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayer numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a2fc00'

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
[customView.tableView reloadData]
```

Comment: Should I try it inside the cycle?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to implement require `UITableViewDataSource` Methods if you are not implemented.

Like:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Yeah, I did that in CustomView class